# ASP.NET MVC AutoComplete - Rely on more then one input field

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I have the jquery autocomplete functionality working.  i.e.  I type in a field and then return data based on the string typed in the field.  My problem is that I would also like to also use data keyed in another field when determining what I should be returning the current field.  For example I only want to return Drivers that belong to a certain company.  This data is inputted in another field. How do I modify the code below to perform this task?  Assume I have a "Model.Company" property.

View (part of it):

```
<%= Html.AutoCompleteTextBox2("DrvId", "DriverID", Model.DrvId, new { style = "width:200px;" })%>           


<%= Html.InitializeAutoComplete2("DrvId", "DriverID", "Driver ID", Model.DrCmpId, Url.Action("Drivers", "AutoComplete"), new { delay = 100, minChars = 1 }, true)%>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Drivers(string q)
    {

        List<TmwXref> driverList = baseService.GetTypeList("Driver");

        for (var i = 0; i < driverList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (driverList[i].Value.StartsWith(q, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                Response.Output.Write("{0}|{1}\r\n", driverList[i].Value + " - " + driverList[i].Description, i);
            }
        }

        return new CancelViewResult();

    }
```

UI Helper:

```
public static string InitializeAutoComplete2<T>(this HtmlHelper<T> html,
                     string textBoxName, string fieldName, string labelName, string fieldDesc, 
                     string url, object options, bool wrapInReady)
    {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (wrapInReady) sb.AppendLineFormat("<script language='javascript'>");

        if (wrapInReady) sb.AppendLineFormat("$().ready(function() {{");
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.AppendLineFormat("   $('#{0}').autocomplete('{1}', {{", textBoxName.Replace(".", "\\\\."), url);

        PropertyInfo[] properties = options.GetType().GetProperties();

        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.AppendLineFormat("   {0} : {1}{2}",
                                    properties[i].Name,
                                    properties[i].GetValue(options, null),
                                    i != properties.Length - 1 ? "," : "");
        }
        sb.AppendLineFormat("   }});");
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.AppendLineFormat("   $('#{0}').result(function(e, d, f) {{", textBoxName.Replace(".", "\\\\."));
        sb.AppendLineFormat("       $('#{0}').val(d[1]);", fieldName);
        sb.AppendLineFormat("    }});");
        sb.AppendLine();
        if (wrapInReady) sb.AppendLineFormat("}});");
        if (wrapInReady) sb.AppendLineFormat("</script>");
        return sb.ToString();

    }

    public static string AutoCompleteTextBox2<T>(this HtmlHelper<T> html, string textBoxName, string fieldName, string value, object htmlAttributes)
    {

        return string.Format("{0} {1}", html.TextBox(textBoxName, value, htmlAttributes), html.Hidden(fieldName));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the second data entry field going to be autocomplete also or a drop down list with list of companies for example?

I'm not sure what your **TmwXref** object looks like but I'm sure you tie your drivers to companies some how.

If it's just a drop down list to select a company to filter on, you could probably just do something similar to:

```
public ActionResult Drivers(string q)
{
    var company = GetSelectedCompanyHere();

    List<TmwXref> driverList = baseService.GetTypeList("Driver");

    for (var i = 0; i < driverList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (driverList[i].Company == company && driverList[i].Value.StartsWith(q, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            Response.Output.Write("{0}|{1}\r\n", driverList[i].Value + " - " + driverList[i].Description, i);
        }
    }

    return new CancelViewResult();
}
```